# Output of catalog_map in R

Tags: r, catalog

i am quite new to R and RStudio, i am currently working with a large set of point cloud data (~450 files), when I try to get the crowns attributes with catalog_map(), I find that the output of the result sometimes being a single sf object (when doing testing with a few LAS files), sometimes being a list of sf objects(when working with whole set of 450files).

should this be expected or did i miss anything?
or how to programmatically tell and bind the list before saving the result with st_write?

Comment: At what poijnt between "a few LAS files" and "a whole set of 450 files" does the behaviour change? Can you provide example code of what you are doing with `catalog_map` (since it might be related to your function)?

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for the reply
the code is as follow
`f_treecrown <- function(las){
    nlas <- normalize_height(las, knnidw())
    tree_tops <- locate_trees(nlas, lmf(ws = getWS, hmin = 20))
    chm <- rasterize_canopy(nlas, 0.3, pitfree(subcircle = 0.2))
    smooth_chm <- terra::focal(chm, w, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
    tree <- segment_trees(nlas, silva2016(smooth_chm, tree_tops, max_cr_factor = 0.44, exclusion = 0.25, ID="treeID"))
    crowns <- crown_metrics(  tree,  type = "convex",  func = .stdtreemetrics, attribute = "treeID", geom = "convex")
    return(crowns)
  }`

Comment: `opt    <- list(automerge = TRUE)   # catalog_apply will merge the outputs into a single object
  output = NULL
  output <- catalog_map(las_catg, f_treecrown, .options = opt)`